# Flannel overlay network as docker container

Tags: docker, networking, flannel

How is possible to run flannel as a docker container whether docker need to know flannel subnet?
Inside etcd i can configure only network and subnets for flannel but i can't assign them to a particulare node, so after flannel start seems that need to restart docker engine but flannel is inside a running container.

Comment: Since overlay network is required for containers, I think it's way better to start flannel system-wide, this will allow you to ensure that docker starts only afterwise. Here is a good guide for it: http://docker-k8s-lab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docker/docker-flannel.html

Comment: @Casey yes this is what do i do at the moment, thanks